# Combination VS permutation problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let's say I want to read $50$ books, one at a time.

The only thing that matters to me in terms of order is that I want to read $3$ books written by Daniel Steele, one after the other, also in any order. And the task is to find the number of possible orders for these $50$ books. I would say that this is a permutation, but I am confused by the phrase "the only thing in terms of order."

My question: Is it a permutation or combination?

Comment: Do the 50 books include just 3 by Daniel Steele? Or do they include more books by Daniel Steele, but you only care about reading 3 of them consecutively (and you don't care which 3 they are)?

Comment: Suppose that you had 15 bricks, and that each brick was regarded as a unit.  These units could be permuted in $(15!)$ ways.  Now suppose that the 1st 5 bricks are to be cemented together into 1 unit, but within this unit the 5 bricks can be in any order.  There are $(5!)$ ways of creating this single large unit.  Once this is done, instead of having $15$ units, you now have only $11$ units.  Therefore, these $11$ units can be permuted in $(11!)$ ways.  Therefore, the final computation re 5 of the 15 bricks fused together would be $5! \times 11!.$

Comment: Yes.  Those 50 books include only 3 by Danielle Steele.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that exactly 3 out of the 50 books are written by Daniel Steele, and the other 47 books have different authors.

Let $b_1,...,b_{47}$ be the 47 books written by authors other than D.S. and let $x$ represent the 3 books written by D.S.

First, lets realize that there are 48! ways to arrange $\{b_1,...,b_{47},x\}$

Now, each of these arrangements, we can arrange the 3 books that $x$ represents in a total of 3!=6 ways.

By the multiplication rule, there are a total of $(48!)(3!)$ ways to read these 50 books if the 3 books written by D.S. are read consecutively.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was helpful a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Andreas Blass 's comment;

Say for example we have 3 alphabets, $[a, b, c]$.

How many **combinations** of $3$ can we make. Only $1$. This is because combinations ignores their order; only takes into account the type of value that is arranged. $^3\mathbb{C}_3$: $([a, b, c] = [a, c, b] = [b, a, c] = [b, c, a] = [c, a, b] = [c, b, a]) = 1$

However, **permutations** differ. Permutations do not ignore the order; each order in independent of each other. How many permutations of 3 are there for the set above.  $^3\mathbb{P}_3$: $([a, b, c] ≠ [a, c, b] ≠ [b, a, c] ≠ [b, c, a] ≠ [c, a, b] ≠ [c, b, a]) = 6$